# Insert several values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert some values into SQL Server but I get an error message:

> Line 2: Incorrect syntax near ','

I need to enter several values in 1 table so I was looking for a quicker way to not insert 1 at a time.

For some reason I always have issues with databases :(

My query is:

```
INSERT INTO PERSONALRH_NIVEL (SERHGCCAB, PUESTO_ID, COMPANIA_ID, REGION_ID, TIPO_EMPLEADO)
VALUES (81570, 4, 2001, 2, 'N'), 
       (81570, 4, 2001, 3, 'S'), 
       (81570, 4, 2001, 3, 'N');
```

Thank you in advance, David

Comment: Your syntax looks fine.  What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: See the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235531/sql-insert-into-select-from-multiple-fields.

Comment: @JimHewitt . . . That question is for MySQL and is not the best method for SQL Server.

Comment: Have you copied the query from other place so the commas could not be real commas?

Comment: This was introduced in SQL Server **2008** - so if you have an older version, or if you database is in a *compatibility level* of an older database, then this syntax will cause errors.

Comment: Well im not sure. Im using sql server management studio, where can i see wich version i have?

Comment: Do a `SELECT @@Version` from within SSMS for server version.  For DB compatability level it's `SELECT compatibility_level  
FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'MyDatabase';`  DB Compatability level matrix is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

Comment: @Gordon My bad.  Just tested in SQL Server and OP's code worked.

Comment: @msanz I have not copied the query but i tried with and without comas.
I also tried this: 

INSERT INTO PERSONALRH_NIVEL (SERHGCCAB, PUESTO_ID, COMPANIA_ID, REGION_ID, TIPO_EMPLEADO)
 VALUES (81570, 4, 2001, 2, 'N'), 
   (81570, 4, 2001, 3, 'S'), 
   (81570, 4, 2001, 3, 'N');
And the error changes to  Line4: Incorrect syntax near '81570'

Comment: @David alright, it was just an assumption, it seems more likely the option that your sql server version is prior to 2008. saludos ;)

Comment: @msanz Ohh thats probably the case then, thanks msanz (Y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For older versions of SQL Server you can use insert from select

```
INSERT INTO PERSONALRH_NIVEL (SERHGCCAB, PUESTO_ID, COMPANIA_ID, REGION_ID, TIPO_EMPLEADO)
SELECT 81570, 4, 2001, 2, 'N' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 81570, 4, 2001, 3, 'S'
UNION ALL
SELECT 81570, 4, 2001, 3, 'N';
```

Comment: Great! it worked, thank you Evgeni you saved my a lot of work :D
And thank you all for your time, it didnt occur to me the version was an issue

Comment: @David I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of SQL Server you are using. Insert Into () VALUES (),() only works in SQL Server 2008 and newer. If you are using SQL Server 2005 you need to use separate Insert statements.